# Obter dados agrupados por mês cumulativamente

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, select, group-by

1. Possuo um sistema de controle de Ordem de serviço
2. Tudo é armazenado na tabela OS que possui os seguintes campos
   **id, data_entrada, data_finalizacao**

Preciso comparar o **número de OS aberta** com o **número de OS finalizada** mês a mês para gerar um gráfico dessa forma
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para obter o numero de OS que foi finalizada mês a mês eu usei o seguinte select

```
select extract(year from data_finalizacao) as ano,
       extract(month from data_finalizacao) as mes,
       count(*) as qtd
from OS
       where 
            data_finalizacao is not null
       group by 
            extract(year from data_finalizacao),
            extract(month from data_finalizacao)
       order by ano, mes asc
```

**Até aqui td OK**

Agora preciso obter a quantidade de OS que estava aberta no final de cada mês

Consigo gerar o dado de 1 mês (fevereiro) usando esse select

```
select count(*)
    from OS
where
    data_entrada < '2022-03-01' and 
    ( data_finalizacao >= '2022-03-01' or data_finalizacao is null )
```

**Como obter todas as OS que não foram finalizadas até o final de cada mês sem precisar gerar um select para cada mês?**

Comment: Você precisa apenas ver onde data `data_finalizacao is null` e dar um `GROUP BY extract(year from data_finalizacao), extract(month from data_finalizacao)`

Answer (score 1):

algo assim

```
select ano,
       mes,
       sum(qtd_finalizada) qtd_finalizada,
       sum(qtd_aberta) qtd_aberta
from
(
/*sql base*/
select extract(year from data_finalizacao) as ano,
       extract(month from data_finalizacao) as mes,
       count(*) as qtd_finalizada,
       0 as qtd_aberta,
from OS
       where 
            data_finalizacao is not null
       group by 
            extract(year from data_finalizacao),
            extract(month from data_finalizacao) 
union all
select extract(year from refers.mesano) as ano,
       extract(month from refers.mesano) as mes,
       0 as qtd_finalizada,
       count(*) as qtd_aberta,
       from OS,(select distinct /*obter os distintos meses da busca)
                       date_trunc('month', data_finalizacao) mesano 
                from OS) refers
where
    data_entrada < refers.mesano and 
    ( data_finalizacao >= last_day(refers.mesano) or data_finalizacao is null ) /*< ajuste o "last_day"*/
    group by by extract(year from refers.mesano),
              extract(month from refers.mesano)
)
group by ano,
         mes
```

atente que que a data final deveria ser maior que o último dia
de cada mês , no Oracle existe uma function pronta **last_day** , não localizei
equivalente no Postgreesql  , mas segue o que achei abaixo

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-date_trunc/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229038/last-day-function-in-postgres

Comment: Acredito que dê pra fazer sem o `union all`, mas não sei se valeria a pena em questão de eficiência e manutenção

Comment: Sem UNION  e fazendo o "em aberto" por CASE, já fiz coisa parecida, optei pelo UNION. Só tem mesmo de tratar o  "em aberto"  com o último dia do mês , pois finalizado em 25/03/2022 não deveria estar como aberto em Março/22